# My gridview has dynamic radio button, on running javascript for confirm my radio button values are lost

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdStaffControl" GridLines="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="grdStaffControl_RowDataBound"  ShowHeader="false" EnableViewState="true" >                    
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="QUESTION" ItemStyle-Width="90%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Left" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%">                
                        <ItemTemplate> 
                            <asp:Label ID="lblQID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ANSWER") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAnswer" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>             
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>                
 </asp:GridView>
```

This is my gridview. Please help.
On any other postback, my values are returned but lost only when javascript for confirm runs.

Comment: please post the whole code and use code tags correctly ;)

Comment: please fix code and add more details

Comment: Please provide javascript confirm code.